# Create a report that could be one page or two, depending on what field was modified

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

In an alternate application, the user has the ability to update their address and phone number.  When these are changed, three fields will update: `Old Value`, `New Value`, and `Field Changed`.  If the `Field Changed` was the address, I need to create two report pages - one with the old address and one with the new.  However, if the `Field Changed` was the phone number, I only need to create one report page for the current address.

My initial plan was to do a `Union` that would have one record with the `Old Value` and another with the `New Value`.  This should work when only the Address has changed.  However, it won't whenever the Phone Number has changed.  I assume I need to do some sort of case statement, but I'm not really sure if this is the right approach.  Sorry if the data is a little confusing (I didn't design the data structure.  This was provided by our professor's assistant).  If you need more information, I'll try to provide it.

I'm not looking for exact SQL, but I am wondering if I'm approaching this the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by a 1 or 2 page report? Are you outputting to a CSV, PDF, XLSX or something eles?

If you need to do this through "pure" sql I would recommend a stored procedure that is given a value stating whether it's the address or phone number that is being updated. It can then do the update and you can simply do an if statement which determines which report to run and return.

I'd recommend handling it programatically if possible. Have your code run the sql update and then call the appropriate function within your code to get the report you need. You can then easily re-use the code for that report in other ways.